# How can we limit the impact of ssh probes?

Tags: ssh, security

My webserver is constantly attacked by various IP addresses. They try five passwords and then change the IP address.

I have done various lockdowns like using ssh-keys and not permitting passwords, and not allowing remote root login.

Is there something I can do to get rid of these attack attempts? Failing that, are there specific defenses I should put up?

Comment: Flagging for a migrate to security.se where it is a bit more on-topic

Comment: @Rory There's a difference between "a bit more on-topic someone else" and "off-topic here" -- it seems pretty clearly on-topic here

Comment: No worries @Michael. Had a ping from Gilles to come and look at it as it was possibly offtopic here.

Comment: @Rory Ok, I'll ask him about it; he's usually pretty good at convincing me something I think is {off,on}topic is actually {on,off}topic

Comment: @MichaelMrozek As stated, this was a poll question (edited). Underneath that is a policy question: what are the threats and what should be done to mitigate them. That primary question is mostly independent of what OS JW01 is running, so off-topic here, but it's a good fit for [security.se]. There's a second question, which is how to implement that policy; this is on-topic here and borderline for [security.se]. The answers here have unsurpringly concentrated on the second question, so I no longer recommend migrating, but I do recommend that JW01 search or ask for policy advice on [security.se].

Comment: My question seems to have been changed beyond recognition. In my original question I was really trying to find out if it was common for _every_ site to experience brute force attacks - i.e. is it a fact of life. This was answered by Matteo with "It is indeed a fact of life.". The second part of the question was asking what i could do to _actively_ stop these attacks **apart from putting up defences**. This would have been a relevant secondary question if only certain sites suffered from brute force attacks. It was answered by Bruce with his tarpit idea. I didn't really ask for defensive tips.

Comment: So - Yes every site suffers from brute force attacks. But, you can make your machine less appealing for attackers by taking an _offensive_ approach and turning it into a tarpit. And, I suppose, if _most hosts_ (or at least, certain distros) were tarpits by default, script kiddies might get bored and the scale of the onslaught may no longer be a _fact of life_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is indeed a fact of life. You can install tools to filter out hosts that are attacking you after a couple of failed attempts.

[DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) analyzes your log files and automatically adds attackers to your `/etc/hosts.deny` file.

Check the documentation on how to configure it for your needs.

**Update**: some important points suggested in the comments

- be sure to properly configure tools as DenyHosts since you could lock yourself out (e.g., you can configure a machine or network that is never filtered)
- DenyHosts does not increase your system security: it only filters attacks at the IP level (it might reduce the load on small machines and reduce the size of the log files but nothing more)

Comment: Aaah. I was beginning to think that I was special. Thanks for putting me straight.

Comment: Extending on Matteo, your question is almost answered exactly `refs Q1.3` http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/faq.html#1_0

Comment: @whoami Thanks for the link, a nice summary. Although one thing that always goes though my mind when I see the _use a different port tip_ is '_how do you know that the alternative port that you choose is not used by something else already?_'

Comment: Be careful with DenyHosts and similar tools, since they introduce additional complexity, i.e. they may create security issues on there own, cf. the 2nd comment on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2942/why-change-default-ssh-port/2944#2944

Comment: Also be careful with DenyHosts because you might lock yourself out of your machine. A simple `apt-get install denyhosts` got me locked out of my machine.

Answer (score 15):

I followed [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20110314071414/http://www.aerospacesoftware.com/howtos/ssh-kiddies.html) to add a 7-second delay to each wrong-password SSH login attempt. I made my sshd into a "tarpit" for the brute-force scanners.

I should also add that I have my modified, tarpit sshd log the failed passwords.  This may not be entirely ethical, as it gives the root user a look at what regular users mis-type as their own passwords, but since I'm the only "real" user, I figure that's OK.

I don't have it run on a non-standard port, as the "tarpit" aspect would not waste anyone's time.

Comment: Also, use a non-standard port and use keys instead of passwords. Then they have almost no hope (providing they don't get ahold of the keys, which should all be passworded anyway).

Comment: This is a nice answer because it has a bit of an 'offensive' approach rather than being [purely 'defensive'](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIIAQME1Uhg) which I think adds to moral.

Answer (score 9):

If only a small number of people need to SSH to the system then consider moving SSH to a non-standard port (e.g. 6422, 8080, etc.) That alone will reduce the number of login attempts greatly (and possibly protect you from some unpatched SSH exploit based worm, for example).

Comment: +1 Rather useful as it limits the annoyance, but do not mistake this for a security measure - this is a closer equivalent of a screen door against mosquitoes than of a security lock.

Comment: +1 This is also a save on server resources.

Answer (score 6):

Concur with @Matteo's answer; what you're seeing is essentially thousands of zombie'd systems executing a distributed brute-force attack on your server because there is a website running on it, which means there may be users that might have a login account that might possibly be guessed with minimal effort on the part of the script kiddie - he's got a program that orders the thousands of zombies to make the bruteforce attempts on a few hundred website hosts at a time and just compile a list of the successful returns.

Similarly, you may sometimes see lots of permuations of "http://your.web.host/phpmyadmin/" in your `/var/log/apache2/access.log` files; these are automated scans for the most common ways of setting up PHPMyAdmin, and  will attempt a number of known exploits if one is found (this, incidentally, is why I've started telling customers to please use the PMA site I personally set up and keep up to date rather than installing their own version and forgetting to keep it updated, but now we're off on a tangent).

Aside from sending out the original command, it doesn't even cost him time or bandwidth; it's fire and forget.

Another very useful bit of software for situations like this is [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/), which uses iptables to block connection attempts after multiple clearly false logon or other exploit attempts.

Answer (score 4):

Try to configure [Fail2ban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban). It provides a very flexible way to search for failed attempts, and it has templates for SSH, HTTP and common services.

Fail2ban will update [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) according to your actions.. I love it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IPTABLES to stop traffic](https://gist.github.com/564856) without running a daemon like Fail2Ban or DenyHosts.

```
#  Allows SSH connections (only 4 attempts by an IP every 3 minutes, drop the rest to prevent SSH attacks)
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --rsource
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 180 --hitcount 4 --name DEFAULT --rsource -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can manage it, I find the best way to deal with stuff like this is to use a VPN.  That way, the only thing they can target is the VPN.  There shouldn't be any services open to the world at large, except those which are necessary for "everyone" to access, such as your web server.  Everything else should be blocked by the firewall.  Now the only thing you really have to worry about securing is your VPN.  If you can, get a static IP for the computers you manage your servers from, and lock your VPN down to that specific IP address. This is really the only way to stop people from trying to brute-force the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

[Sshguard](http://www.sshguard.net/) works great. I'm using it together with iptables.