# How do I switch users on Amazon Linux for EC2 instances?

Tags: sudo, users, su, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I saw

- [How to change to normal user in the command line when logged in as the root user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156962/how-to-change-to-normal-user-in-the-command-line-when-logged-in-as-the-root-user)
- [How to switch between users on one terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-to-switch-between-users-on-one-terminal)

I have access to `sudo`. I tried

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-99-99-99 Weekly Report]$ sudo su - jenkins
Last login: Tue Jan 29 20:26:37 UTC 2019 on pts/0
Last failed login: Tue Jan 29 20:32:30 UTC 2019 on pts/0
[ec2-user@ip-172-99-99-99 Weekly Report]$ id; whoami
uid=500(ec2-user) gid=500(ec2-user) groups=500(ec2-user),10(wheel)
ec2-user
[ec2-user@ip-172-99-99-99 Weekly Report]$ touch tmp.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘tmp.txt’: Permission denied
[ec2-user@ip-172-99-99-99 Weekly Report]$ ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x 7 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan 28 09:00 .
```

I need to execute commands as the Jenkins user to troubleshoot Maven issues.

Comment: Does the jenkins user share a uid (500) with ec2-user?

Comment: No they don't. From `/etc/passwd`: `ec2-user:x:500:500:EC2 Default User:/home/ec2-user:/bin/bash\n
jenkins:x:498:497:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment the default shell is set to `/bin/false`

As the user jenkins you can use `chsh` to change this permanently.

Alternatively if you don't want to perminantly change it you can just run bash as jenkins with:

```
sudo -u jenkins /bin/bash -l
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```