# how to pkg upgrade on freenas (freebsd)

Tags: freenas

I've installed a freenas server on a new server which I try to host on my own. Then I created a volume (ZFS) over 3*5TB harddisks. Last I logged in via ssh as root and tried to `pkg upgrade` all packages. This wouldn't work:

```
[root@kfreenas] ~# pkg update
Updating local repository catalogue...
pkg: file:///usr/ports/packages/meta.txz: No such file or directory
repository local has no meta file, using default settings
pkg: file:///usr/ports/packages/packagesite.txz: No such file or directory
Unable to update repository local


[root@kfreenas] ~# pkg upgrade
Updating local repository catalogue...
pkg: file:///usr/ports/packages/meta.txz: No such file or directory
repository local has no meta file, using default settings
pkg: file:///usr/ports/packages/packagesite.txz: No such file or directory
Unable to update repository local
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking for upgrades (0 candidates): 100%
Processing candidates (0 candidates): 100%
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Your packages are up to date
```

Somewhere I read that I've to do first `pkg2ng`. This resulted in many lines like this:

```
...
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/include/X11/Xalloca.h): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/include/X11/Xarch.h): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/include/X11/Xatom.h): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/include/X11/Xdefs.h): No such file or directory
...
```

BTW: pkg -vv:

```
[root@kfreenas] ~# pkg -vv
Version                 : 1.7.2
PKG_DBDIR = "/var/db/pkg";
PKG_CACHEDIR = "/var/cache/pkg";
PORTSDIR = "/usr/ports";
INDEXDIR = "";
INDEXFILE = "INDEX-10";
HANDLE_RC_SCRIPTS = false;
DEFAULT_ALWAYS_YES = false;
ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES = false;
REPOS_DIR [
    "/etc/pkg/",
    "/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/",
]
PLIST_KEYWORDS_DIR = "";
SYSLOG = true;
ABI = "FreeBSD:10:amd64";
ALTABI = "freebsd:10:x86:64";
DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
VULNXML_SITE = "http://vuxml.freebsd.org/freebsd/vuln.xml.bz2";
FETCH_RETRY = 3;
PKG_PLUGINS_DIR = "/usr/local/lib/pkg/";
PKG_ENABLE_PLUGINS = true;
PLUGINS [
]
DEBUG_SCRIPTS = false;
PLUGINS_CONF_DIR = "/usr/local/etc/pkg/";
PERMISSIVE = false;
REPO_AUTOUPDATE = true;
NAMESERVER = "";
HTTP_USER_AGENT = "pkg/1.7.2";
EVENT_PIPE = "";
FETCH_TIMEOUT = 30;
UNSET_TIMESTAMP = false;
SSH_RESTRICT_DIR = "";
PKG_ENV {
}
PKG_SSH_ARGS = "";
DEBUG_LEVEL = 0;
ALIAS {
    all-depends = "query %dn-%dv";
    annotations = "info -A";
    build-depends = "info -qd";
    cinfo = "info -Cx";
    comment = "query -i \"%c\"";
    csearch = "search -Cx";
    desc = "query -i \"%e\"";
    download = "fetch";
    iinfo = "info -ix";
    isearch = "search -ix";
    prime-list = "query -e '%a = 0' '%n'";
    leaf = "query -e '%#r == 0' '%n-%v'";
    list = "info -ql";
    noauto = "query -e '%a == 0' '%n-%v'";
    options = "query -i \"%n - %Ok: %Ov\"";
    origin = "info -qo";
    provided-depends = "info -qb";
    raw = "info -R";
    required-depends = "info -qr";
    roptions = "rquery -i \"%n - %Ok: %Ov\"";
    shared-depends = "info -qB";
    show = "info -f -k";
    size = "info -sq";
}
CUDF_SOLVER = "";
SAT_SOLVER = "";
RUN_SCRIPTS = true;
CASE_SENSITIVE_MATCH = false;
LOCK_WAIT = 1;
LOCK_RETRIES = 5;
SQLITE_PROFILE = false;
WORKERS_COUNT = 0;
READ_LOCK = false;
PLIST_ACCEPT_DIRECTORIES = false;
IP_VERSION = 0;
AUTOMERGE = true;
VERSION_SOURCE = "";
CONSERVATIVE_UPGRADE = true;
PKG_CREATE_VERBOSE = false;
AUTOCLEAN = false;
DOT_FILE = "";
REPOSITORIES {
}
VALID_URL_SCHEME [
    "pkg+http",
    "pkg+https",
    "https",
    "http",
    "file",
    "ssh",
    "ftp",
    "ftps",
    "pkg+ssh",
    "pkg+ftp",
    "pkg+ftps",
]
ALLOW_BASE_SHLIBS = false;
WARN_SIZE_LIMIT = 1048576;


Repositories:
  local: { 
    url             : "file:///usr/ports/packages",
    enabled         : yes,
    priority        : 0
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aren't really supposed to use the shell on the main FreeNAS host, and so the `pkg` repositories are disabled.

If you want a shell on the machine you should look at creating a [Jail](http://doc.freenas.org/9.10/freenas_jails.html) (like a lightweight virtual machine) and use that for shell access.

If you *really* want to use `pkg`on the main FreeNAS host and you're confident that you can clean up any mess you make, look in `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf`. But personally I'd use a Jail.

Also, it's [generally considered bad practise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/why-is-root-login-via-ssh-so-bad-that-everyone-advises-to-disable-it) to enable root ssh on a system.

Comment: This answer is top hit for several related topic searches outside SE. Helped, thanks. Source or reference for the first sentence? Or what one is 'supposed' to use rather than pkg from the host?

Comment: if you encounter the same issue reported by OP while trying to install a package *inside* a jail, try disabling IP6 by adding `ipv6_enable="NO"` in `rc.conf`. That helped in my case since I don't have ipv6 DNS configured.

Comment: @JoelReid apologies, I’ve looked on and off for a reference since you asked. I can’t find a written one, but I recall Kris Moore staying it multiple times on the BSDNow podcast. I’ve not tracked it down, but it would be on an episode between 2014 and 2017 - a long period I know, hence why I’ve not gone back through to listen…