# Disable Root Password Login... but can I SUDO with a GUI SFTP program?

Tags: security, sudo, root, sftp

I fully understand why [I should disable Root login on a production server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/why-is-root-login-via-ssh-so-bad-that-everyone-advises-to-disable-it).  That makes sense.  I can log in as username, then sudo back to root functions just fine from the terminal.

What I'm unable to do is utilize a graphic type of secure file transfer protocol (SFTP) tool (e.g. filezilla) to get access to key directories.  Is there a way to keep the root login disabled and use SFTP, or am I stuck using a terminal $ ssh login with <kbd>wget</kbd> or <kbd>curl</kbd> for all of my file transfer needs?

The problem is that I can only use <kbd>wget</kbd> or <kbd>curl</kbd> for content loaded on a server somewhere.  I can't directly upload content from my laptop/desktop development machine to the server.  Yes, I am aware that <kbd>git</kbd> style transfers are an other possibility.  I would need a private git repo somewhere to make that work.

Is there a way to set a <kbd>sudo</kbd> access for the SFTP tool, without using a root login?

Is there an alternative method to send new content to a online server via remote access, without compromising security?

Same thing goes for downloading / reading systems content.  I know I can do a lot of things via terminal and `su -` or `sudo`, but I have to say, reading a systems log file that is 10 megs long is just out of the question with `vim` or `nano`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can sudo via sftp but if you can somehow setup so sudo would not ask for a password (for example use `!tty_tickets` and run any command with sudo beforehand, or `your-user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/tar *`) then you can do something like:

```
    tar cf - /some/dir | ssh your-user@your-server.com "sudo tar xf - -C /some/dir"
```

But then again, giving your user passwordless root access to tar is also a security consideration, so maybe only do it while you are transfering the files.