# Mount root filesystem with user permission using sshfs

Tags: permissions, mount, sshfs, readonly

I want to use `sshfs` to mount filesystem folder on my machine (let's say `~/home`).

I would like to be able to edit files inside the `/` folder that got mounted using any editor (for example, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`).

In a nutshell, I want to use `sshfs` to mount my entire server file system in my Desktop with r+w+x permissions for every file

I tried looking for answers around here, but got nowhere and only could mount with "read-only" permissions. The command was:

```
sshfs hostname@ip.address:/ ~/Desktop -o max_conns=8,transform_symlinks,dir_cache=yes,idmap=user,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),reconnect -d -v -C
```

Comment: That sound like a giant security hole which is probably why you can't get it going.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco yes, but in theory it should be possible, right?

Comment: I can only edit files inside the /home/ folder from the server, however, it is not possible to edit any files inside the root filesystem `'/'`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no, I disabled root login access to the server using ssh. (ie. the user from hostname@ip.address has sudo privileges, but it's not root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sshfs hostname@ip.address:/ …` acts on the server side as the same user you would log in with `ssh hostname@ip.address`, so most likely `hostname` (kinda misleading name, it's a user). If `hostname` is not equivalent to `root` on the server then it's normal you cannot edit arbitrary files.

The SSH server (daemon) like `sshd` runs and listens as `root`. It forks to serve your request. After you authenticate as `hostname` you eventually are served by `sshd` that dropped its privileges and runs as `hostname`. This way you can only do on the server what `hostname` can do.

This works regardless of what you see locally. The options `idmap`, `uid` and `gid` cannot overcome the fact `sshd` on the server works as `hostname` for you. These options are meant to make the local mount look sane in the local environment.

To be able to edit the remote `/etc/sysctl.conf` file locally, you need to authenticate to the server as a user who can edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` on the server. This applies to any file. Two basic options:

1. You can mess with permissions on the server. Dangerous. E.g. if you make `/etc/sudoers` too open  on the server then `sudo` will refuse to work there.
2. Allow yourself to do `sshfs root@ip.address:/ …`. [Not recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82626/108618).

One way or another, what you want to do is not really a safe idea.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a connection string like in Tramp in Emacs
`ssh:myuser@server|sudo:server:/path/requires/root` (with passwordless sudo on `server` for `myuser`)