# Operation not permitted when writing in sshfs

Tags: rsync, sshfs

I use image-backup to backup my Rpi. I backup directly on an FTP server and I do so via sshfs.

This is how I connect in my /etc/fstab:

```
MYUSERNAME@MYSERVER:/home/myuser/rpi_backup /mnt/MYSERVER fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,reconnect,identityfile=/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions 0 0
```

Here my /etc/fuse.conf

```
user_allow_other
```

I get the error that I dont have permissions:

```
rsync: [generator] symlink "/tmp/img-backup-mnt/boot/cmdline.txt" -> "firmware/cmdline.txt" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

I have tried also the following commands but this didn't fix it:

```
sudo groupadd fuse
sudo usermod -a -G fuse pi
```

Someone has an idea of what else I could try to fix this?

Many thanks!

EDIT:

So in the end it isn't SSHFS at all.

When using `sudo image-backup` and then enter the destination /mnt/test.img I get the same error.

I understand that a custom program is difficult to troubleshoot and to look whats wrong but what rsync commands can I test to reproduce or narrow down the errors?
Thanks.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701487/108618

Comment: Why `sudo echo foo >>file` "fails" is that the `>>file` is handled by the parent shell, running as `$USER`, before `sudo` is executed.

Comment: I removed the part with sudo echo in my question. This works now for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

> I removed the part with sudo echo in my question. This works now for some reason.

@waltinator already explained it in his comment, here is the long version:

A command line is interpreted by the shell in several distinct steps. One of these steps - a rather early one - is to process redirections. This is why a command like:

```
sudo -s /some/command > /some/where
```

is **NOT** interpreted as "*pass `/some/command > /some/where` to `sudo -s`*" but the redirection is processed first and the output of `sudo -s /some/command` is redirected to `/some/where`. Only then `sudo` is called and passed the option `-s` and the command line argument `/some/command`.

This means, that a process running under *your* user ID and with *your* privileges writes to the redirection target and presumably your privileges don't encompass writing there.

The solution is to create a process which is indeed able to write there:

```
sudo -s /some/command | sudo -s tee [-a] /some/where > /dev/null
```

You see, both the "/some/command" and the "tee" which does the writing run with elevated privileges.

Notice that you need to use the "-a" flag if you want to append the file, leave it out for overwriting the file. Also notice that you need to redirect the output of `tee` to `/dev/null` if you don't want to have what is written to the file clutter your screen.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have removed the « echo » part of my question as I understood my wrongdoing. Having said this, my problem with sshfs is still unsolved.