# Rsync: operation not permitted

Tags: rsync

I use image-backup to create a backup of my entire system.

For some reason it doesn’t work and I just can’t get it going.

When running the command `sudo image-backup` and then enter /mnt/test.img I get this error:

```
rsync: [generator] symlink "/tmp/img-backup-mnt/boot/cmdline.txt" -> "firmware/cmdline.txt" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: [generator] symlink "/tmp/img-backup-mnt/boot/config.txt" -> "firmware/config.txt" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: [generator] symlink "/tmp/img-backup-mnt/boot/overlays" -> "firmware/overlays" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]

Unable to create backup
```

I talked to the developer and he couldn’t pinpoint it either and suggests it is specific to my system.

Someone has an idea what I could try?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not really going to be possible to troubleshoot a custom-written script/program without seeing it.

Comment: What system are you running this on (version and/or distribution)? Where is this `image-backup` tool available from? How did you invoke it? What is the exact `rsync` command that it's using? What does `/mnt/test.img` represent? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/766259/edit) to provide this information (no need for "edit" statements; just update the question as if you had provided it originally)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Update your original at  [Operation not permitted when writing in sshfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765613/operation-not-permitted-when-writing-in-sshfs) if you have new information

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say based on next to no information. At a guess: the target device has a file-system that doesn't support symlinks, like fat or ntfs.